# Socket hangs on jdbc preparedstatement and callablestatemet when adding more than 59 bytes across columns

Tags: sql-server, jdbc

I am using ms-sql jdbc 6.4 jre8 driver. Database server is MS sql server 2016. Both application and database sits on different machines. There is a firewall in between.
The callable statement is pretty basic. I am only setting up varchar columns. When I set the varchar columns from jdbc using callablestmt.setString(1, "abc"); such that it is combined bytes length of all strings is less than or equal to 59 my insert into the table works fine. The Moment I add any additional character in setString for any of the columns, my statement execution hangs at execute().
I have tried the following so far,

- Tried changing tcp buffer send and receive. no luck
- Tried using dbcp and bone cp connection pool. Didnt work.
- Changed jdc driver to jtds, didnt work
- Max connection pool is 50 , min pool size is 30

Note that if execute normal statement i.e statemet.execute it works fine.
I shall update the code if required.
Please let me know any pointers, solutions.

Edit#1 - Added Code
Edit#2 - Correct Stored procedure for nullable values
**Stored Procedure**

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE schema.usp_insert_or_update_sample
@c1 varchar(10),
@c2 varchar(4) = NULL,
@c3 varchar(30),
@c4 varchar(4) = NULL,
@c5 date = NULL,
@c6 int = NULL,
@c7 varchar(1) = NULL,
@c8 varchar(18) = NULL,
@c9 varchar(40) = NULL,
@c10 decimal(13,3) = NULL,
@c11 decimal(13,3) = NULL,
@c12 decimal(11,2) = NULL,
@c13 decimal(13,2) = NULL,
@c14 date = NULL,
@c15 date = NULL,
@c16 varchar(1) = NULL,
@c17 varchar(4) = NULL,
@c18 varchar(2) = NULL,
@c19 varchar(16) = NULL,
@c20 varchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1   FROM   schema.sample  WHERE  c1 = @c1 AND c20 = @c20)
UPDATE schema.sample
SET c1 = @c1,
c2 = @c2,
c3 = @c3,
c4 = @c4,
c5 = @c5,
c6 = @c6,
c7 = @c7,
c8 = @c8,
c9 = @c9,
c10 = @c10,
c11 = @c11,
c12 = @c12,
c13 = @c13,
c14 = @c14,
c15 = @c15,
c16= @c16,
c17 = @c17,
c18 = @c18,
c19 = @c19,
c20 = @c20,
lud = GETDATE() WHERE  (c1 = @c1 AND c20 = @c20)
ELSE
INSERT INTO schema.sample (
[c1],  [c2], [c3],  [c4], [c5],[c7], [c8], [c9],
[c10],  [c11], [c12], [c13], [c14], 
[c16], [c17], [c18], [c20], [c19], [cd], [lud])
VALUES  (
@c1, @c2, @c3, @c4, @c5, @c7,   @c8, @c9, 
@c10, @c11, @c12, @c13, @c14, 
@c16, @c17, @c18, @c20, @c19,
GETDATE(), GETDATE())
END
```

Edit#2 - updated code to correctly populate length of each column
**JDBC code**
Also, In this code when the length is more than 55 bytes it just hangs. If Tweaking value of c8 from 12345678912345 (working case) to 123456789123456 failing case.

```
            /*
            Table                       Procedure
            c1 varchar(10) not null,    c1 varchar(10),
            c2 varchar(4),              c2 varchar(4) = NULL,
            c3 varchar(30) not null,    c3 varchar(30),
            c4 varchar(4),              c4 varchar(4) = NULL,
            c5 date,                    c5 date = NULL,
            c6 int,                     c6 int = NULL,
            c7 varchar(1),              c7 varchar(1) = NULL,
            c8 varchar(18),             c8 varchar(18) = NULL,
            c9 varchar(40),             c9 varchar(40) = NULL,
            c10 decimal(13,3),          c10 decimal(13,3) = NULL,
            c11 decimal(13,3),          c11 decimal(13,3) = NULL,
            c12 decimal(11,2),          c12 decimal(11,2) = NULL,
            c13 decimal(13,2),          c13 decimal(13,2) = NULL,
            c14 date,                   c14 date = NULL,
            c15 date,                   c15 date = NULL,
            c16 varchar(1),             c16 varchar(1) = NULL,
            c17 varchar(4),             c17 varchar(4) = NULL,
            c18 varchar(2),             c18 varchar(2) = NULL,
            c19 varchar(16),            c19 varchar(16) = NULL,
            c20 varchar(50) not null,   c20 varchar(50)
            cd datetime not null,   
            lud datetime not null   

            */
            if (conn != null) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Preparing Call - usp_insert_or_update_sample");
                    callSt = conn.prepareCall(
                            "{call staging.usp_insert_or_update_sample(?,  ?,  ?,  ?,  null, null,  ?,   ?,  ?,  null,  null,   null, null, null, null, ?,   ?,   ?,  ?,   ?)}");
                    //                                                                     c1, c2, c3, c4, c5,   c6,   c7,  c8, c9, c10,   c11,    c12,  c13,  c14,  c15,  c16, c17, c18 c19, c20
                    //                                                                     10, 4,  30, 4,  dt,   in,   1,   18, 40, dm,,   dm,     dm,   dm,   dt,   dt,   1,   4,   2,  16,  50  
                    callSt.setQueryTimeout(20);
                    conn.setAutoCommit(false);
                    System.out.println("Ready to set parameters");

                    String c1 = "1", c2 = "1", c3="1", c4="1", c5="", c6="", c7="1", c8="1",
                        c9="123456789012345678901234567890123456789", c10="", c11="", c12="", c13="", c14="", c15="", c16="1", c17="1", c18="1", c19="123456789012345", 
                        c20="1234567890123456789012345678901234567";

                    String[] columns = {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9, c10, c11, c12, c13, c14, c15, c16, c17, c18, c19, c20};

                    int totalBytes = 0;
                    for(String column: columns){
                        totalBytes = totalBytes + column.getBytes().length;
                    }

                    System.out.println("Total number of bytes " + totalBytes);

                    callSt.setString(1, c1);            //c1
                    callSt.setString(2, c2);            //c2
                    callSt.setString(3, c3);            //c3
                    callSt.setString(4, c4);            //c4
//                  callSt.setString(5,c5);             //c5
//                  callSt.setString(5, c6);            //c6
                    callSt.setString(5, c7);            //c7
                    callSt.setString(6, c8);            //c8
                    callSt.setString(7, c9);            //c9
//                  callSt.setDouble(10, c10);          //c10
//                  callSt.setString(9, c11);           //c11    
//                  callSt.setDouble(12, c12);          //c12 
//                  callSt.setDouble(13, c13);          //c13
//                  callSt.setString(14, c14);          //c14
//                  callSt.setString(15, c15);          //c15    
                    callSt.setString(8, c16);           //c16
                    callSt.setString(9, c17);           //c17
                    callSt.setString(10, c18);          //c18
                    callSt.setString(11, c19);          //c19
                    callSt.setString(12, c20);          //c20
                    System.out.println("\nExecuting");
                    callSt.execute();
                    System.out.println("\nExecuted");
                    conn.commit();
                    System.out.println("Committed");
```

**Execution Logs Failing Scenario**

```
Length of data (bytes) 55
Executing
21-Apr-2018 12:43:32.067 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-7] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.buildExecSQLParams SQLServerCallableStatement:31: calling sp_executesql: SQL:EXEC staging.usp_insert_or_update_sample @P0, @P1, @P2, @P3, null, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7, null, @P8, null, null,null, null, @P9, @P10, @P11, @P12, @P13
```

**Execution Logs Working Scenario**

```
Ready to set parameters
Looping 0
Length of data (bytes) 54
Executing
21-Apr-2018 12:46:32.129 FINE [https-jsse-nio-8443-exec-3] com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.buildExecSQLParams SQLServerCallableStatement:32: calling sp_executesql: SQL:EXEC staging.usp_insert_or_update_sample @P0, @P1, @P2, @P3, null, @P4, @P5, @P6, @P7, null, @P8, null, null,null, null, @P9, @P10, @P11, @P12, @P13                                                      

Executed
Committed
```

Also note the following exception, when I kill the tomcat container due to hung state,

```
java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
 java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1981)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSReader.readPacket(IOBuffer.java:6310)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.startResponse(IOBuffer.java:7545)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:465)
 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:409)
```

It looks to be waiting to read something, but what it is waiting for I am not sure and why only in some cases only.

Comment: Please add all of the relevant code, including the stored procedure you're calling.

Comment: @MickMnemonic Updated required details.

Answer (score 0):

I reduced the MTU of the client server where client application resides and it worked.